# How to group priority in TestNG for each class?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

When I execute my testNG project, it is mixing up all the Tests from different classes which i add under the same `<test>` based on the priority. How do i code so that, I need to run all the methods on first class in order of there priority before moving to the next class?

```
 <test name="test1">
    <classes>


        <class name="class1" />
        <class name="class2" />

    </classes>

</test>
```

Edit on 16Dec2019 :

**Here is my sample Code :**

Class 1:

```
public class LearningTestNG extends masterClass
   {

   @Test
   public void test()
      {
      System.out.println("Priority 0 (Default in Class 1)");
      }

   @Test(priority = 1)
   public void test2()
      {
      System.out.println("Priority 1 (Class 1)");
      }

   @Test(priority = 0)
   public void test3()
      {
      System.out.println("Priority 0 (Class 1)");
      }

   @Test(priority = 1)
   public void atest4()
      {
      System.out.println("Priority 1 (Class 1)");
      }

   }
```

Class 2 :

```
public class LearningTestNGTest2 extends masterClass
   {

   @Test(priority = 0)
   public void testin_LearningTestNGTest2_Class()
      {
      System.out.println("Priority 0 (Class 2)");
      }

   }
```

XML :

```
<classes>

    <class name="testclasses.LearningTestNG" />
    <class name="testclasses.LearningTestNGTest2" />

</classes>
```

OUTPUT :

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.12.0

Priority 0 (Default in Class 1)
Priority 0 (Class 1)
Priority 0 (Class 2)
Priority 1 (Class 1)
Priority 1 (Class 1)

===============================================
suiteNameGiveninXML
Total tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 0):

In class1 , if you have used priority=1 then 2 and then 3 and so on under @Test of class1 then Test methods in the priority of 1,2,3... will be executed first and then control will move to class2 once the class1 gets completed under test name="test1".

Comment: But if there is a test in class 2 with priority 2 then it will be executed before the one in class 1 with priority 3. I want to stop moving to class2 before all tests in class 1 are finished. isnt that possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, class2 with priority=2 won't be executed before class1 with priority=3.Please see the below example.

```
public class AppTest 
{

@Test(priority=1)

public void Test1()

{

System.out.println("Test1");

}

@Test (priority=2)

public void Test2()

{

System.out.println("Test2");

}

@Test(priority=3)

public void Test3()

{

System.out.println("Test3");

}

@Test(priority=4)

public void Test4()

{

System.out.println("Test3");

}

}

public class AppTest1 
{

@Test(priority=1)

public void Test1()

{
System.out.println("Test1");
}

@Test (priority=2)

public void Test2()

{

System.out.println("Test2");

}

@Test(priority=3)

public void Test3()

{

System.out.println("Test3");

}

}
```

Also, Can you please share your example in which you are getting class2 method with priority=3 before class1 .

Comment: I have added my Sample Code in the question

Comment: I am getting below output which is expected :Priority 0 (Default in Class 1)
Priority 0 (Class 1)
Priority 1 (Class 1)
Priority 1 (Class 1)
Priority 0 (Class 2) .. You are getting priority 0 (class2 ) before priority 1 (class1 ) because your classes are extending master class which might have some code that is impacting the execution order . Please remove master class and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In your testng.xml use `group-by-instances="true"` to apply priority classwise.

**Test Class-1:**

```
public class TestClass1 {

    @Test( priority = 1 )
    public void testA1() {
        System.out.println("testA1");
    }

    @Test( priority = 3 )
    public void testA2() {
        System.out.println("testA2");
    }

    @Test( priority = 5 )
    public void testA3() {
        System.out.println("testA3");
    }

}
```

**Test Class-2:**

```
public class TestClass2 {


    @Test( priority = 2 )
    public void testB1() {
        System.out.println("testB1");
    }

    @Test( priority = 4 )
    public void testB2() {
        System.out.println("testB2");
    }

    @Test( priority = 6 )
    public void testB3() {
        System.out.println("testB3");
    }


}
```

Please have a look on sample xml file.

```
<suite  name="testSuite">
<test name="MytestCase" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.ui.test.TestClass1" />
        <class name="com.ui.test.TestClass2" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

**Output:**

```
testA1
testA2
testA3
testB1
testB2
testB3
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: No this did not work for me. edited the XML as in yours but still i got the same output

Comment: I have ran your code. It is working for me and output is  Priority 0 (Default in Class 1)
Priority 0 (Class 1)
Priority 1 (Class 1)
Priority 1 (Class 1)
Priority 0 (Class 2)

Comment: what is your output and what version you are using for Testng Jar/Dependency and plugin?

Comment: Output is in the question. TestNG i am using is this one(installed using Help->Eclipse marketplace) : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/testng-eclipse?mpc=true&mpc_state=

Comment: version for Testng Jar/Dependency ? Please paste your full testng.xml in question. The solution is in Testng.xml.

Comment: Testng Plugin not available from marketplace if you don't  know check comments on Page from your given URL. For me it is absolutely working fine. Probably you are missing something. The output you have mentioned in question will come without 'group-by-instances="true" ' in xml file.